# How to implement AMPHTML Ads for my AMP pages

Tags: ads, amp-html

Please guide me on how to add AMPHTML Ads for my AMP pages as AMPHTML Ads has more advantage of loading speed over the normal amp-ad.

Answer (score 0):

Raky, please look at the documentation for this. There are plenty of resources that you can look through

https://amp.dev/about/ads

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-a4a/amp-a4a-format.md

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-ad/amp-ad.md